# RDWeb Error 403 by choosing other Physical Path of Default Site

Tags: windows, iis, iis-8, remote-desktop, rdp

the last days I tried to set up a Windows Server 2012 R2 IIS 8 Web-Server with the Laravel Framework and RDWeb.

RDWeb worked perfectly, until I tried to use Laravel.

The Problem is that I need to change the physical path of the Default Web Site form **C:\inetpub\snx** [image] 
to **C:\inetpub\snx\public**
[image]
and everytime I try this RDWeb write Error 403, if I want to open an rdp session by clicking on an item[image].

RDWeb Page if it does not work: [image]

So the Error occurs every time I change the physical path to a "deeper" physical path.

Can you help me please?

Thank you

SUT_2

---

Here is the F12 Screenshot.
Something is forbidden - but I don't know how to solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: I can't quite see the browser that you are using, but if you click F12, there should be a button that allows you to inspect elements on the page. Can you please hover over some of the broken elements (i.e.: the images in the picture above) and see where they point? RDWeb puts the icons and RDP files that are needed to display properly in some paths, so Laravel might take over those URLs, thus resulting in an error.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I put a screenshot next to this post.
@cdavid

Comment: One more question (BTW, you should edit your initial question and add the screenshots there): is your RDWeb website hosted at https://<<hostname>>/RDWeb or some other URL? That might interfere with the handling of URLs such as /RDWeb/Pages...

Comment: It is normally hosted at https://.../rdweb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem - I just delted the web.config File in laravels /public-Folder.

Now, Laravel and RDWeb works - I hope I don't have further problems.

Thank you for your answers.